# Is it possible to have a generic Rust T be always heap allocated?

Tags: rust, unsafe

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Test {
    last: &'static str,
    list: Vec<String>,
}

// This is safe because we own the value and will not modify it.
// When dropping, `last` will be dropped without freeing the memory.
impl Test {
    pub fn new(value: String) -> Self {
        Self {
            last: unsafe { std::mem::transmute(value.deref()) },
            list: vec![value],
        }
    }
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: String) {
        self.last = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(value.deref()) };
        self.list.push(value);
    }
    pub fn last(&self) -> &str {
        self.last
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do a similar construct with generics, something like `Test<T:Deref>`?  I am not sure `deref()` guarantees any "permanent"  heap address (in the limited context of my implementation), or does it?

The above code seems safe because calling `deref()` on a `String` gives a wide pointer to heap, and that address would never change unless the string itself is altered or the ownership is returned to the caller.

Note that I need to store `&str` for my use cases rather than use `ManuallyDrop<String>` created with `ManuallyDrop::new(unsafe { ptr::read(&value) })`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suspect, this is not safe.

There exists the [`stable_deref_trait`](https://docs.rs/stable_deref_trait) that provides the [`StableDeref`](https://docs.rs/stable_deref_trait/latest/stable_deref_trait/trait.StableDeref.html) trait that is supposed to be used for such use-case. However, [this crate is known to be unsound](https://github.com/Storyyeller/stable_deref_trait/issues/15) (or at least, used in unsound ways), since, for example, it implements `StableDeref` for `Box` [but it is not clear whether it is okay to move a `Box` while there are references to it](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/issues/326) (under Stacked Borrows, this is UB, and Miri will flag it as such).

If you want to be 100% safe, heap-allocate all stored objects and store them as `*mut T` (**not** `Box<T>`, for the reason mentioned above), then you can store references to them within the same struct.

Comment: Thanks for a great reply!  Could you elaborate what you mean by heap-allocate but not store as box?  I always thought that `Box::new(T)` is the way to heap-alloc. Alternative is of course to do a `vec![T]`, but that seems wasteful, as it may have more than one element even when using `with_capacity`

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan The problem with `Box` (explained in the linked issue), is that even though it heap-allocates, if you move the `Box` it is possible that all existing pointers to it are invalidated and from now on accessing their content is UB.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Even worse, the linked issue says "box **and vec**". That sounds like the OP's original (non-generic) code is also unsound, because the reference was obtained from `String` which got moved into the `Vec` (and the `Vec` itself can then move). But I couldn't get MIRI to flag anything, so maybe that's too paranoid (or MIRI just doesn't catch that case).

Comment: @user4815162342 which issue are you referring to?  If 326, my quick reading does not imply `Vec` usage would be UB, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan Yes, I was referring to #326, I didn't notice two issues are linked from the answer. You're probably right regarding `Vec`, but I'm not 100% sure. At least the issue description explains why MIRI doesn't flag it.

Comment: @user4815162342 It is true that the debate is also around `Vec`, but (a) OP doesn't use `Vec` but `String`, and it is even less likely to not work and (b) although the desired semantics of `Box` are questionable, for `Vec` it's almost clear that we don't want moves to invalidate pointers to its elements. This is also the semantics Miri implements, and this is why you couldn't trigger it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Agreed on all counts.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman technically (AFAIK) `String` is implemented as a `Vec<u8>`, isn't it?

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan Yes, it is.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman but the point above is that `Vec` is not as safe as `String`?  So if one is implemented with the other, why are they different in safety?

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan Currently, `Vec` (and therefore also `String`) are not special in this regard, neither by the compiler's optimization nor by Miri. My gut feeling is that even if we want `Vec` to invalidate references, we don't want `String` to, so if this will ever be implemented `String` will be changed to something else. But this is just my gut feeling.